# Access not configured error message

Tags: google-mirror-api

I've set up oauth and am properly retrieving an access token.

Here is the response I get from hitting

`https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubTokenInfo?access_token=<token>`

```
parsed_response="Target=645428735890.apps.googleusercontent.com\nSecure=false\nScope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile\nScope2=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email\nScope3=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.timeline\nScope4=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.location\n"
```

which I believe properly shows that I have requested the correct permissions.

A call to

`https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline?access_token=<token>`

yields:

`"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"usageLimits", "reason"=>"accessNotConfigured", "message"=>"Access Not Configured"}]`

Having trouble figuring out what this means. I don't have an actual piece of glass hardware. The docs make it seem like this access token would allow me to make any requests to the mirror api.

Is there an additional setup or permission I need to ask for that I missed? On the application side? Is this related to my google account and having not set up glass?

EDIT:

Okay, from the authorization docs:

`Select the Services tab in your API project, and enable the Google Mirror API.`

However, I'm not seeing Google Mirror API listed on the services tab?

Comment: This answer may be what you are looking for: [Google Glass Development Error: (403) Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208870/google-glass-development-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mirror API is currently in [developer preview](https://developers.google.com/glass/devprev) and access is limited to I/O Explorers who have received their Glass device. You can subscribed to this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=2) on our issue tracker to get updates on when the Mirror API will be public.

Comment: understood, thank you. surprised i didn't find that in my searches. will keep an eye on that thread.